# Installed texlive, but can't find it on hard drive

Tags: texlive, installing

I am using KUbuntu 14.04 and just re-installed it after setting up a new computer. Instead of `texlive-full` I installed `sudo apt-get install texlive texlive-lang-german texlive-doc-de texlive-latex-extra` from [ubuntuusers.de](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/Tex_Live). I also installed Kile.

1.) Now, when I try to identify my texlive-folder or wherever Linux installed the stuff with `locate texlive` and/or `locate tex-live` I can not find it. So where is it?
2.) Also I don't know how to choose PATH for `tlmgr`.

I am really afraid of installing anything again or removing something, since last time, it just totally messed up everything big time!! Even dpkg was damaged and I had to set uo KUbuntu again. I really don't have time for this now, so what went wrong and what can I do?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: There's no program called `texlive`, so try `locate latex.ltx`. Also try entering `latex --version` in the terminal.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for the quick response. Will not find 'latex.ltx', sorry.

Comment: Run `sudo updatedb` to update the database of `locate` or use `whereis latex`.

Comment: `aptitude show texlive`

Comment: `latex --version` gave:
`pdfTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian)
kpathsea version 6.1.1
Copyright 2013 Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.

...

Comment: ... 


Primary author of pdfTeX: Peter Breitenlohner (eTeX)/Han The Thanh (pdfTeX).
Compiled with libpng 1.2.49; using libpng 1.2.50
Compiled with zlib 1.2.8; using zlib 1.2.8
Compiled with poppler version 0.24.5`

and `aptitude show texlive` gave:

Comment: `Package: texlive
Priority: optional
Section: tex
Installed-Size: 93,2 kB
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Original-Maintainer: Debian TeX Maintainers <debian-tex-maint@lists.debian.org>
Source: texlive-base
Version: 2013.20140215-1
Depends: texlive-latex-recommended (>= 2013.20130512), texlive-fonts-recommended (>= 2013.20130512), texlive-latex-base (>= 2013.20130512)
Download-Size: 14,2 kB
Homepage: http://www.tug.org/texlive/
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Origin: Ubuntu
Supported: 9m

Comment: APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
Description: TeX Live: Eine anständige Auswahl der TeX-Live-Pakete
 Die Softwaredistribution TeX Live bietet ein komplettes TeX-System. Es
 enthält Programme zum Setzen, zur Vorschau und zum

Comment: Ausdrucken von TeX-
 Dokumenten in vielen verschiedenen Sprachen sowie eine große Sammlung von
 TeX-Makros und Schriftbibliotheken.
 .
 Dieses Metapaket stellt eine anständige Auswahl von TeX Live Paketen zur
 Verfügung, die für die meisten Aufgaben genügen sollte.
 .
 Die Distribution enthält auch ausführliche allgemeine Dokumentation über
 TeX sowie die Dokumentation der enthaltenen Software-Pakete.`

So what does that mean now? Before I had folders in `/usr/local/texlive/...`

Comment: BTW. - you guys are really quick....

Comment: According to http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/all/texlive-base/filelist it should be in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist`.

Comment: It is, thank you. Just ask myself, why `locate` does not find it

Comment: Run `sudo updatedb`, as I mentioned above.

Comment: not working, sorry

Comment: `locate` doesn't find recently added files, because it does a lookup in a table that's generated periodically. One can force updating, but TeX Live has its own method: `kpsewhich latex.ltx` will return the path where the LaTeX kernel main file resides.

Comment: there's always the brute force approach: `find / -name texlive | less`

Comment: If you install the upstream version (TeX Live 2014 using the net installer or iso), you'll have stuff installed in `/usr/local/texlive/`. If you install the version packaged by Debian/Ubuntu, you'll have stuff installed in `/usr/share/...`.

Comment: @cfr: he _said_ he installed using `apt-get`; that (on my machine) puts the stuff in `/usr/share/texlive-bin` and  `/usr/share/texmf-texlive` and similar

Comment: @wasteofspace Exactly ;).

Answer (score 2):

Try the command

```
kpsewhich latex.ltx
```

to locate your TeX installation. On my system it gives the location

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/latex.ltx
```

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely forgotten to enter the installation path into the file "/etc/environment"
Enter the full path, which is most likely 
"/usr/local/texlive/2014/bin/x86_64-linux/" into the line "PATH:"
Note: You need to edit the file with sudo rights and entries are separated with a colon ":"

Comment: he installed using `apt-get`, so there should be no immediate need to change the path list variable: my similar system has `latex` in `/usr/bin`

Comment: Oops, should have read your question more carefully. @Gabriel: What is your problem then ? Why do you want to enter a path for "tlmgr". If you did install with "apt-get" then Kile will find it and you can start writing with it. The program "tlmgr" will only be available if you do a "TeXLive" installation independently from the xUbuntu sources.